# Does a Draconic Bloodline sorcerer's doubled proficiency bonus for Charisma checks against dragons apply to all dragon types or only the chosen one?

Tags: dnd-5e, sorcerer, dragons, proficiency

The [Draconic Bloodline sorcerer](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/sorcerer#DraconicBloodline) gets the Dragon Ancestor feature at 1st level, part of which says:

> Additionally, whenever you make a Charisma check when interacting with dragons, your proficiency bonus is doubled if it applies to the check.

Does the doubled proficiency bonus to Charisma checks apply to such checks in dealing with all dragons, or only the selected dragon ancestry type?

Comment: Welcome to the site! If you have the time, feel free to take our [tour]. Great question here. I made a small edit to make the title more detailed, and quoted the text of the feature so it is more clear what you are referring to. If I have changed the meaning of your question, feel free to revert my changes, and add more detail as to what you are actually asking. Happy gaming!

Answer (score 19):

### It applies to all dragons

Since the feature doesn't specify that it is limited to the dragon you choose, it applies to all dragons. The only aspect of the feature that is influenced by the dragon you choose is the damage type that is later associated with different features:

> ... you choose one type of dragon as your ancestor. The damage type associated with each dragon is used by features you gain later.

The features this affects are Draconic Resilience and Elemental Affinity.